# pm2 has multiple copies of an executable in its list

Tags: pm2

Here is the output of `pm2 ls`

[image]

Why are there multiple `keys_server`'s and how can they be removed?

P.s. If anyone knows why the vertical bars are not being rendered properly feel free to pitch in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `pm2 delete <id>` works. After doing

```
 pm2 delete 0
 pm2 delete 2
```

The list is:

[image]